# How to fit a single quadratic term to a regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, kernel-trick, quadratic-form

I have a high dimensional multivariate model and am fitting  linear weights to each of the $N$ free variables using a classic stable SVD matrix solver. This works.
I want to improve the fit by using a higher order model. I could of course use a full quadratic regression by adding the $N^2$ cross terms to the regression. But this makes my model where $N\approx 1000$ far too unwieldy. Instead I first tried a classic simple eigenvector based Principle Component Analysis to find the top 10 "primary" directions of my data and used those augmented variables for $\approx 10^2$ cross terms.  This worked well but I feel it may be improved more.

I wonder if it's possible to mathematically find the **optimal** axis for a single quadratic term instead of hoping the PCA eigenvector directions are best.
That is, given my many linear variates, I want to make a single extra augmented column which is the square of a weighted sum of the other columns. I want to chose those weights such that the total regression fit (linear regression columns plus this new quadratic term) is has the minimal least squared error.  But I can't figure out how to determine these $N$ optimal corefficients!  I suspect this is a quadratic programming problem, perhaps one that's solvable with a Lagrangian multiplier.

I appreciate any hints. I am sure others have done this kind of fit "augmenting" before, but I haven't found any papers or references to guide me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly your regression problem is. Can you clarify? Do you have one dependent variable or many? You wrote "multivariate", which means that you have many DVs (how many?); if so, how do you even measure the quality of the "fit"?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a partial least squares approach as an alternative to PCA. Conceptually, you could run (quadratic, N^2) PLS on the residuals left after your chosen multi-variate linear regression.